# Как перевести строку std::string в нижний регистр?

Tags: macos, boost, xcode, c++

Встала задача - необходимо получить строку из стандарного ввода и перевести ее в нижний регистр. Нужно обойтись инструментами `STL` и `Boost`.  Вот варианты которые я использую:

```
std::string str;
getline(cin, str);
boost::to_lower(str);

std::string str;
getline(cin, str);
boost::algorithm::to_lower_copy(str);

std::string str;
getline(cin, str);
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Эти варианты работают, но работают только  со строками латиницы, а при обработки русских текстов никаких изменений не происходит. 
И любая попытка использовать в коде `std::locale`

```
std::locale locRus("RUS");
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
                   std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&std::ctype<char>::tolower), &std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(locRus)));
```

вызывает примерно такую ошибку:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
> uncaught exception of type
> std::runtime_error:
> collate_byname<char>::collate_byname
> failed to construct for RUS

Comment: @derkode, это вечные проблемы.

Если делаете что-то серьезное, то делайте **свои преобразования** (и лучше *платформозависимые* (как это ни странно звучит)).

Comment: Я попытался в ручную сделать это: `std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 'А', 'а');` Говорит: `Character too large for enclosing character literal type`. Что-то C++ вообще не подпускает к великому и могучему. Какой ручной вариант будет лучше друзья?

Comment: У Вас там что в маке -- utf-8?

Comment: Да. Он по моему на всех *unix.

Comment: Посморите [ucsutf.c](http://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW)  и [ucsutf.h](http://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL)

Это чистый Си и по моему, там только для кириллицы. Может вытащите что-то полезное для себя.

Comment: а wstring не работает тоже?

Comment: Вот, кажется, правильный ответ. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24063783/276994

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что используете std::string, а русский текст - это юникод. Соответственно вам нужен std::wstring.